# Full height on mobile after keyboard is opened and closed

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
  <!-- This outlet div is where the views are rendered -->
  <div id="outlet"></div>
<body>
```

and CSS styles:

```
  <style>
    body, #outlet {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
```

Everything works fine on desktop browsers, but on iPhone, when the popup keyboard appears, the screen does not correctly recalculate the height. After I close the keyboard, the page contains white space at the bottom.

[image]

Please show how to fix these styles in order to work properly with full height on mobile screens.